# How to use a loop to loop to the amount of times as a variable

Tags: javascript, for-loop

This is my assignment from class, but my professor won't respond to my emails and i'm having trouble.

> Write a script that asks for a user's name and age, then prints the user's name and age on the screen over and over until it loops as many times as the user's age.  Security Feature: Do not let users named "Raymond" run this program.

Here is my code:

```js
let name = prompt("What is your name?");
let age = prompt("What is your age?");

for (age = 0; age <= 19; age++) {
  document.write("Your name is " + name + " and your age is " + age + "</br>");
}
```

Comment: Where do you check if the name is `Raymond`?

Comment: `age = 0` overwrites the variable that contains the user's age.

Comment: Where does `19` come from? You're supposed to repeat it as many times as the user's age, not your age.

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation for loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your attempt is here in the for loop.

```
for (age = 0; age <= 19; age++)
```

That will overwrite the age that the user entered, and always loop until it reaches 19. You want to create a new loop variable, then loop until the age the user entered.

```js
let name = prompt("What is your name?");
let age = prompt("What is your age?");

for (i = 1; i <= age; i++) {
  document.write("Your name is " + name + " and your age is " + age + "</br>");
}
```

The other issue is that you don't do anything about users named "Raymond" using your program. You can do that with an if..else statement around the loop.

```js
let name = prompt("What is your name?");
let age = prompt("What is your age?");

if (name === "Raymond") {
    document.write("Get out of here, Raymond! You know what you did!");
}
else {
  for (i = 1; i <= age; i++) {
      document.write("Your name is " + name + " and your age is " + age + "</br>");
  }
}
```

Comment: This was precisely what I needed, and I see now that I need to set a different variable to age within the for loop. Thank you so much!